# Discrete Math: determine the number of six digit integers (no leading zeros)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

**- Background Information:**

I am studying discrete mathematics, as I was practicing, I came across this problem and solution in my textbook. However, I cannot fully understand the solution. I need some clarification, thanks.

**- Question:**

> Determine the number of six-digit integers (no leading zeros)
>   in which (a) no digit may be repeated; (b) digits may be
>   repeated. Answer parts (a) and (b) with the extra condition that
>   the six-digit integer is (i) even; (ii) divisible by 5; (iii) divisible
>   by 4.

**- Textbook Solution:**

For part b i)

> ANSWER:
>   case 1:(9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 1) for integers ending in 0.
>   case 2: (8 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4) for integers ending in 2,4,6, and 8.
>
> result: case 1 + case 2 = 68,800

**- My Questions:**

Why do we start with 8 and not 9?  Could you please explain how case 2 is structured?

Comment: Also it would be great if someone can explain how does this down vote process works ? Like what did I post wrong that people think it should be down voted ?

Comment: Ciruss, this is the wrong site. This site is for professional mathematicians and their PhD students to discuss questions arising in their research. May I inquire why you post here and not somewhere else (did you look into what MO is about before you posted)?

Comment: Sorry, I am a new user. I am gradually getting used to the website.

Comment: @user43208 I'm also a new comer and searching for exact same question and found this one helpful for me. What is the MO you mentioned? Where else should those question being post? At least this question helped me more than the question you left un-clarified.

Comment: @Mengo I'm glad this question helped you. There seems to be no notice of this anymore, but this question was originally posted at MathOverflow, or MO for short. MathOverflow is the StackExchange site for professional mathematicians, and what happened was that the question was deemed off-topic for the clientele there, and so it was migrated here where it found its proper and happy home. That's what my comment that appears here was about (the comment was originally posted at MO but remained here even after the migration). Make sense?

Comment: And indeed, if you hit the 'blue' where it says 'edited', you can see the history of this question, where the migration itself is noted in version 1 of this post. So, you see, it wasn't that I 'left the question unclarified'. It's that the software did its thing and you are seeing the relics (can't think of just the right word) of what happened at MO.

Comment: @user43208 Ah, thanks for clarification. The criteria of `professional mathematicians` in MO is still confusing to me, do we consider have to have a math PHD diploma to ask question there? Because MO dose not have any restrictions on registration.

Comment: I get the point that this question might not fit the clientele there, but I don't think it deserve downvote and throw away so people with curious mind and courage to ask questions gets disappointed.

Comment: @Mengo No, a PhD is not required. But in practice, the vast majority are researchers in mathematics who do or are planning to make mathematics their profession, including professors, post-docs, PhD students. The real criterion is the level of question; a question like the above would be considered an undergraduate homework exercise that is trivial for the MO clientele, hence inadmissible. By the way, the downvote you see was given by a Math.SE member; if you hover over the downvote button, you see the criteria. Probably they thought the OP didn't show any effort.

Comment: @Mengo In case you haven't done it already, you might want to take a "guided tour" to help answer questions like "why is a question downvoted?", etc. I think you'll find it if you click the question mark button at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the six digits $D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_6$. In case two, the order in which we are choosing them is $D_6, D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_5$.

- For $D_6$, there are four choices: 2, 4, 6, 8.
- For $D_1$, there are eight choices: all nine of 1-9 (**can't start with zero!**), except $D_6$.
- For $D_2$, there are eight choices: all ten of 0-9, except $D_6$ and $D_1$.
- For $D_3$, there are seven choices: all ten of 0-9, except $D_6$ and $D_1$ and $D_2$.
- For $D_4$, there are six choices: all ten of 0-9, except $D_6,D_1,D_2,D_3$.
- For $D_5$, there are five choices: all ten of 0-9, except $D_6,D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4$.

Comment: Fantastic my friend, thank you!

Comment: The key to understanding this problem was placing the specific numbers in sets for example D1 , ... , D6